# Information about grep cammand

Tags: grep

Both two outputs came in my terminal.

```
sda              13.45       479.55        84.92     812139     143808


sda               5.00     4.90         4.00          13         24
```

I want to get second line using grep command. please tell me how to do it.

Comment: You should have done Google to find the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sed command pipielined to grep

```
grep "sda" |sed -n '2'p
```

if its the second line do this   else provide the specific line number

Comment: thanx bro....... :)